# Como um usuário novo pode sugerir criação de novas tags?

Tags: suporte, tags

Sou um usuário novo e creio que, assim como outros usuários experientes mas sem acesso a funcionalidade de propor novas tags, não tenho como fazer isso. O .pt.stackoverflow é um site novo e, de fato, a pontuação para criar tags não é alta e acredito que não mereça ser alterada. Porém, faço a pergunta:

**Como um usuário novo pode sugerir novas tags?** Pode ser por algum chat do pt.stackoverflow.com? Se sim, qual seria o chat mais indicado?

Especificamente falando, senti falta da tag joomla. Já existe a drupal e wordpress.

Answer (score 8):

Pode ser na própria pergunta, desde que você edite depois para retirar essa parte que não seja mais relevante. Ou pode ser em comentário. Também seria bom apagá-lo depois.

Claro que nem sempre seu pedido será atendido. Ele precisa ser razoável. A inclusão da tag precisa fazer sentido na pergunta e ela precisa ser relevante para o site. Quase sempre é, mas tem alguns raros casos que você precisará aceitar que a tag não é boa. **na teoria** usuários mais experientes deveriam saber melhor quando criar uma tag :)

O seu exemplo mesmo, deveria ser criado, claro.

Comment: Pode sugerir aqui no meta também